# What is the correct way to initialise a trait's fields at construction

Tags: scala

I'm relatively new to Scala, and am trying to code some basic object-relational mapping for a hobby project. I have classes representing my application domain objects, for example:

```
class Employee(val name:String)
```

I would like my ORM layer to record the database key with this employee, but this should not clutter the public Employee class. I thought I could use a trait for this:

```
trait DBEntity {val id:Int}
```

Within my ORM layer, when an employee is queried, I would return:

```
new Employee("Bob") with DBEntity {val id=5}
```

This will allow my ORM layer to later retrieve the id for an employee. My questions are:

1) Is this the best way to mix-in the trait? It boils down to creating an inline anonymous class, I would have preferred something like `new Employee("Bob") with DBEntity(5)`, but traits can't have constructor parameters so this won't compile.

2) I am considering making Employee a case class to aid matching later on, would the new anonymous subclass returned by the ORM layer still be suitable for matching?

Comment: Values of types other than `case class`es may be matched upon, but to do so you must write your own so-called extractor. It's not often necessary but it's good to know about.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly valid, but you might find it cleaner to have `Employee` subclass `DBEntity`.  In this case you'd possibly want to make the `id` field a `def` in the trait and override it with a `val` in the `Employee` class.

Either way, pattern matching will work on the case class.

Comment: The problem is I would like to keep DBEntity out of the public hierarchy - I do not want client code of Employee to know or care about DBEntity. I guess in Java I would accomplish this with a DBEntity interface, and have a package-protected subclass of Employee in the ORM package that implements DBEntity. This allows me to instantiate a new Employee without inventing a fake ID (for example when adding a new employee), while allowing the ORM to keep track of employee instances instantiated by it.